# Which of the following points lie in the same connected component of X as the origin?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=R^2-\{(x, y)\mid 3x + 5y + 1 = 0\}$. Which of the following
   points lie in the same connected component of X as the origin?

a. $(−1, 2)$

b. $(2, −1)$

c. $(1, −2)$

i was trying this question many times but i could not able to solve this question, i was putting  $(−1, 2)$ in  $3x + 5y + 1 = 0$ but $(−1, 2)$ did not satisfy the given equation. i think option a) is not correct, similarly $(2, −1)$ also not satisfy the $3x + 5y + 1 = 0$.
But i think I'm in wrong track...i don't know how can i solved this question.

If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him

Comment: I don't think you're interpreting the question correctly. Can you describe in a geometrical sense what $X$ is, using a few words?

Comment: im very weak in topology, i was just applying the coordinate  in given equation as did in system of linear equation @ michael lee

Comment: You don't need to know any topology, just what the definition of the set $X$ is. $X$ is part of the plane, right? It's some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. More specifically, what does $X$ look like?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The line defined by $3x+5y+1=0$ divides the plane in two components. The first is the set of points such that $3x+5y+1<0$ the second is $3x+5y+1>0$.

Comment: im not getting,,,,,from ur hints,,,i think all option a) , b) and c) are correct@ Tsemo  aristide

Comment: Remark that $3(0)+(0)+1>1$, what point between $a,b,c$ verifies that

Comment: option a) and option b) are correct  because both are greater than zero if we put in the given equation i,e from option a) 3.(-1) + 5(2) +1  and 3(2) + 5(-1) both are greaten then 0 @ tsemo Aristide